# Time values from xlsx interpreted differently for 2 files of identical format

Tags: r

I have two excel (xlsx) files that contain time data in the format h:mm:ss.000. The file formatting is, as far as I can tell, identical, but I get different values after importing to R.

Using `gdata::read.xls()`, the time column gets imported as a factor; however for some files, it is in the format of hh:mm:ss.000, while in others it is just numeric (I think epoch, except when I try to convert using `as.POSIXct()`, I get times that are off by 10 minutes - possibly a rounding error?  I'm converting from factor using `as.numeric(as.character(x))`.)

I have googled around and can't find what could be causing this.  The excel column formats are identical.

I've shared the files here: http://www.filedropper.com/badexcel

ff3 is coming in as I want it (h:mm:ss.000), while ff10 gets read in as numeric (though both are as factors).

code:

```
require(gdata)
require(dplyr)

ff3 <- read.xls("ff3.xlsx", sheet = 2)
ff10 <- read.xls("ff10.xlsx", sheet = 2)
ff3 <- select(ff3, Code:Timestamp)
ff3<- filter(ff3, Timestamp!="[...]")
ff10 <- select(ff10, Code:Timestamp)
ff10 <- filter(ff10, Timestamp!="[...]")
head(ff3$Timestamp)
head(ff10$Timestamp)
as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(devdata$Timestamp)), origin = "1970-01-01", tz="MST")
```

Results:

> head(ff3$Timestamp)
>
> [1] 17:02:40.160 17:03:00.420 17:03:52.980 17:04:00.760 17:04:10.850 17:04:14.270
>   12 Levels: [...] 17:02:40.160 17:03:00.420 17:03:52.980 17:04:00.760 ... 17:07:13.350
>
> head(ff10$Timestamp)
>
> [1] 42097.360296296298000 42097.360625347224000 42097.361245254629000 42097.361760763888000
>   [5] 42097.362458912037000 42097.362762384262000
>   15 Levels: [...] 42097.360296296298000 42097.360625347224000 ... 42097.364464467595000
>
> as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(devdata$Timestamp)), origin = "1970-01-01", tz="MST")
>
> [1] "1970-01-01 04:41:37 MST" "1970-01-01 04:41:37 MST" "1970-01-01 04:41:37 MST"
>    [4] "1970-01-01 04:41:37 MST" "1970-01-01 04:41:37 MST" "1970-01-01 04:41:37 MST"
>    [7] "1970-01-01 04:41:37 MST" "1970-01-01 04:41:37 MST" "1970-01-01 04:41:37 MST"
>   [10] "1970-01-01 04:41:37 MST" "1970-01-01 04:41:37 MST" "1970-01-01 04:41:37 MST"
>   [13] "1970-01-01 04:41:37 MST" "1970-01-01 04:41:37 MST"

Question: Why are the import results different, how can i ensure they are the same 
OR
What is wrong with the numeric values that using as.POSIXct() isn't converting correctly?

**EDIT:** 
I've tried additional xls reading packages as Joran suggested, and am getting the same result, suggesting that its something about the xlsx files.  I have tried saving them as CSV and the time formats are identical (hh:mm:ss.000).  Any excel experts have an idea what might be causing this?

For anyone trying to open them, the circular reference is intentional (I allow a single iteration), but it is not necessary to enable circular references to view the data.

Comment: You have many, many options these days for reading in xlsx files. I would try some others before you spend much time trying to get `read.xls` to work. There are **xlsx**, **XLConnect** (Java) packages, **openxlsx** (no Java) and **readxl** (on github only at the moment, but people seem to like it).

Comment: The contents of those cells are formulas. I get a warning about circular references from (at least) this formula that appears in c2: `=IF(B2<>"",IF(C2="[...]",NOW(),C2),"[...]")`

Comment: Thanks Joran, I will try a few others.

Comment: BondedDust - The circular reference is necessary for timestamping entries in adjacent columns, and requires that allowed iterations be set to one to work.  However, that is beside the point.  Both files have the same formulas and formats.  One imports in h:m:s (ff3), the other doesn't (ff10).

Comment: If I remember, Excel stores dates internally as a floating point number. And so does POSIXct.